# Remove window event handler after triggered one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dealing with an odd problem where I need an event handler to bind upon instantiation of a module, but when the module is terminated via a click or a keypress, I no longer want this global event bound.  I've gotten the click event to register termination of the module handled elsewhere in code and that works, but the problem is the escape press that I want to globally terminate the module regardless of where my user currently is in the app.

My problem is that the .off() doesn't appear to work given the circumstances.

```
let tools = {};
//how can i eliminate this next line of code after escape has been triggered?
$(window).on('keydown', (e)=>escape(e, tools));
function escape(e, tools){
    if (e.which==27){
        //do some stuff with tools, etc
        $(window).off('keydown', $(window), escape); //this line doesn't seem to work
        alert('alert triggered, but next time escape is pressed it wont.');
    }
}
```

Am I going about this approach wrong?  I tried binding it to the div element itself, but this has a whole lot more baggage associated with focussing the div to recieve the keypresses, and if the user navigates to another module, the escape will no longer be triggered because this module will no longer have focus, and well, etc etc etc.

Thank you!

Here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rbfebL5y/1/

Comment: To add additional information, the alert should only trigger one time, but in the above example, it keeps triggering.  That is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only handler function as argument according to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
let tools = {};
//how can i eliminate this next line of code after escape has been triggered?
$(window).on('keydown', escape);
function escape(e){
    if (e.which==27){
        //do some stuff with tools, etc
        $(window).off('keydown', escape);
        alert('alert triggered, but next time escape is pressed it wont.');
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider taking out the `//this line doesn't seem to work` bit as it makes your answer rather confusing

Comment: answer for this works. just refresh the jsFiddle if you've updated it to the same code.

Comment: The problem wiht this is that tools inside the function escape is undefined.

Comment: I need to have access to the tools object inside this function.

Comment: @simon fixed: anyway you have tools defined in parent scope so you dont need to pass it as argument

Comment: got it!  ok thank you I'll accept now.  I just have to tweak code a little bit and it understand what I am referencing.  tools in this case was a property of the entire module, but if i make a quick reference as you suggested above it to define it as a variable, it works.  thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use localStorage:

```
// check key pressed and whether we've done this before
if (e.which==27 && !localStorage.getItem('hasLoggedEscape')){
    // set the local storage value saying we've done this before
    localStorage.setItem('hasLoggedEscape', 1);
    //do some stuff with tools, etc 
}
```

later if you want to reset this, do

`localStorage.removeItem('hasLoggedEscape');`

Comment: Upvoting your answer, but I'm avoiding localstorage for now.  If this is my only route, I'll accept.  Reason being that I am a state nazi, and dealing with localstorage is keeping a state elsewhere.

I'm confused why $(window).off doesn't seem to be working. or if thats a limitation of .off() itself.

Comment: @simon if the user presses escape, then reloads the page. and then presses escape again, should the event fire the second time, or no?